# automated pull from FTP into git

Tags: git, deployment, ftp

Ofcourse I am using GIT to manage my code. But now a client asks me to deploy to an FTP server and they are likely to also change files on the FTP server.

You can imagine I don't want to download the entire project everything, so I want to do a sort of `pull` from FTP server.

`git-ftp` is unstable for me. It almost never works as it should (on `pull`).

Does anyone have any solutions for automated fetching changes from the FTP server?

Comment: Do you have an ssh access to the server ?

Comment: sadly, no. I don't control the server.